# find minimum value of $u$ for $\,u = \frac{ax^2+by^2}{\sqrt{a^2x^2+b^2y^2}}$

Tags: lagrange-interpolation

Find the minimum value of $u$ where

$x^2+y^2=1\;$ and $\;u =\displaystyle{\dfrac{ax^2+by^2}{\sqrt {a^2x^2+b^2y^2}}}$

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Let $$E=a^2x^2+b^2y^2$$

$$(a+b)\left(a x^2+b y^2\right)=E+a b\left(x^2+y^2\right)=E+ab$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{a x^2+b y^2}{\sqrt{E}}=\frac{\sqrt{E}}{a+b}+\frac{\left(\frac{a b}{a+b}\right)}{\sqrt{E}}$$